# How to navigate between screens from any js class that is not inside App.js in React Native

Tags: react-native

It's very easy to navigate from one screen to another that is inside App.js class. What I have done is made three classes : App.js, SearchList.js and Detail.js. But i am facing issue that how to navigate from searchList.js to Detail.js on click any view inside searchList.js class. Should i use StackNavigator again in searchList.js or declare all classes in App.js ?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image,Button, View, Text ,StatusBar,StyleSheet,Platform,TouchableOpacity,ImageBackground,Picker,Alert,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator,DrawerNavigator,DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';
import {Constants} from "expo";
import SearchList from './classes/SearchList';
import Detail from './classes/Detail';

const DrawerContent = (props) => (
  <View>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#f50057',
        height: 160,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>
        Header
      </Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
  </View>
)

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

 static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./images/crown.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: '#f50057'}]}
      />
    ),
  };

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={PickerValueHolder : ''}
  }

  GetSelectedPickerItem=()=>{
    Alert.alert(this.state.PickerValueHolder);
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <ImageBackground  source={require('./images/green.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >

       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
         <Image
          source={require('./images/menu-button.png')} 
          style={styles.imagesStyle}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>


        <View style={styles.columnContainer}>

          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.search} underlayColor='#fff'  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchList')}>
            <Text style={styles.searchText}>Search Hotels</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
         </View>

        </ImageBackground >

    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  search:{
    marginTop:20,
    paddingTop:15,
    borderRadius:8,
    borderColor: '#fff'
  },
  searchText:{
      color:'#fff',
      textAlign:'center',
  }
     //  backgroundColor: '#ef473a', // app color
});

const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: null,
    })  
  },
  SearchList: { screen: SearchList },
  Detail: { screen: Detail},
});

const RootStack = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    DetailsScreen: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

SearchList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Platform, View, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, Image, Alert, YellowBox,ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator,} from 'react-navigation';
import Detail from './classes/Detail';

export default class SearchList extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {isLoading: true}

   YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    'Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated',
  ]);

 }

GetItem (flower_name) {

 Alert.alert(flower_name);

 }

 FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
   return (
     <View
       style={{
         height: .0,
         width: "100%",
         backgroundColor: "#000",
       }}
     />
   );
 }  

 webCall=()=>{

  return fetch('https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/FlowersList.php')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: responseJson
           }, function() {
             // In this block you can do something with new state.
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });

 }

 componentDidMount(){

  this.webCall();

 }

 render() {

   if (this.state.isLoading) {
     return (

      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>

         <ActivityIndicator size="large" />

       </View>

     );

   }

   return (

     <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

       <FlatList

        data={ this.state.dataSource }

       ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

        renderItem={({item}) => 

              <ImageBackground  source= {{ uri: item.flower_image_url }} style={styles.imageView}  
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')}>
                </ImageBackground>

          }

        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

        />

     </View>
   );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex:1,
    margin: 5,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight , //(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 14,
},

imageView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 220 ,
    margin: 7,
    borderRadius : 40,
},

});


const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
 Detail: { screen: Detail},
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <HomeStack  />;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: You should import that .js in App.js

Comment: But i want to navigate from second.js to third.js. Suppose on any button click . How importing that .js in App.js will work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate to any screen you need to have a navigation object. Navigation object can be provided in two ways

1. By declaring it in `StackNavigator`
2. By explicitly passing it as a prop to some other screen

If you use the first approach, and you need to navigate from `SecondScreen` to `ThirdScreen`, both of your screens should be declared in the `StackNavigator` first, only then navigation will be successful.

If you are using any trivial component ( such as a modal box ) to navigate to another screen, all you need to do is pass the navigation props (`this.props.navigation`) to the modal box component and use the props to navigate to another screen. The only requirement here being, `this.props.navigation` should be available in the class where the modal box component is loaded.

**EDIT**

As requested, here is the snippet

```
const App = StackNavigator({
    FirstScreen: { screen: FirstScreen},
    SecondScreen: { screen: SecondScreen},
    ThirdScreen: { screen: ThirdScreen}
})

export default App;
```

In your `SecondScreen`, declare an object `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` and on a button click, use this object to navigate to another screen `navigate("ThirdScreen");`

Regarding the second approach, if your component is a modal, you can pass the `navigate` object as - `<Modal navigation={navigate} />` and in the modal component you can use it as `this.props.navigation("ThirdScreen");`

Hope it clarifies now.

Comment: can you please explain programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Support we have `js` named `SecondScreen.js` at the same directory level as `App.js` then we should import it like this in `App.js`

```
import SecondScreen from './SecondScreen';
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps to you too.

Comment: my question is about navigate from second.js to ThirdScreen.js  not from app.js to SecondScreen.js. Please mark that all classes are in same directory level

Comment: @manpreetkaur you can do it the same way, importing ThirdScreen.js in your SecondScreen.js, I think

Comment: @manpreetkaur share your code with me on github or dropbox if possible

Comment: can you share via dropbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166794/discussion-between-ppl-and-manpreet-kaur).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement the functionality of a stack navigator. 
Go to [React-Navigation-Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation.html). In stack navigator you can make stack of screens, and navigate from one to another. Inside index.js :

```
    import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
    import SplashScreen from "./src/screens/start/splash";
    import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/start/login";
    import DomainScreen from "./src/screens/start/domain";


        const App = StackNavigator(
          {
            Splash: {
              screen: SplashScreen,
            },
            Domain: {
              screen: DomainScreen,
            },
            Login: {
              screen: LoginScreen,
            },
            Tabs: {
              screen: HomeTabs,
            }
          },
          {
            initialRouteName: "Splash",
          }
        );
AppRegistry.registerComponent("app_name", () => App);
```

then you can navigate to any of these screens using `this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenName")`

Comment: You are right i'm using stack navigator but issue is i have to mention all screens in App.js . But i dont know how to navigate from suppose 
 from DomainScreen to LoginScreen like on click any view of DomainScreen it redirect me on LoginScreen

Comment: I am not getting you, you can simply make a TouchableOpacity or a Button or a Text component and pass a onPress props to it and in this,make a anonymous function and write your navigating code there ?

Comment: Alright! So what you're doing wrong is trying to navigate to "Details" screen but you've named it "Detail". rename it and I guess everything would work fine.

Comment: try navigating to "DetailsScreen"